# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'. > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformExceptionduplicate entry:

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am working with firebase notification and since this noon i am getting this error.

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'. > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/gcm/PendingCallback$1.class

Build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: 'config.gradle'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "********"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 25
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
compileOptions {

}

aaptOptions {
    cruncherEnabled = false
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        shrinkResources true
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debug {
        debuggable true
    }
}
}
android.buildTypes.each { type ->
type.buildConfigField 'String', 'CHAT_SERVER_URL', "\"$chatServerUrl\""
}
repositories {
    jcenter()
maven {
    url 'http://tokbox.bintray.com/maven'

}
maven {
    url 'https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk-releases/raw/master/'
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})

compile files('libs/picasso-2.5.2.jar')
compile("com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-chat:2.5.1@aar") {
    transitive = true
}
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.6.0'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
compile 'me.himanshusoni.chatmessageview:chat-message-view:1.0.7'
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.20.0'
compile 'at.blogc:expandabletextview:1.0.3'
compile 'com.github.aakira:expandable-layout:1.6.0@aar'
compile 'com.opentok.android:opentok-android-sdk:2.10.+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.2.6'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.6'
//    compile 'com.google.android.gms.internal.zzanb:10.2.6'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:10.2.6'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.6'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.6'
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.5.2'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.6.0'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.stripe:stripe-android:4.0.1'
compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.13.0'
compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.6'
compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.0.2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.11.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.2.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.6.0'
compile 'com.github.bmelnychuk:atv:1.2.+'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: We can't help without seeing your Gradle files

Comment: well, there is something wrong with your libraries.

Comment: wait i am adding my build.gradle file in question

Comment: i added it in my edited qustion

Comment: @VladMatvienko i know something is wrong with libraries but where at it is  occure? please suggest me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to remove **compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.2.6'** from your module gradle file .

**PendingCallback** is the class that duplicate in both **Firebase** and old **GCM** .
Once you remove **'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.2.6'** from your gradle file you will find some compile errors that depends on **'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.2.6'** .

You have to replace that code with new google **Firebase** API code .
Hope it help you .